# how to upload image in laravel bootstrap auth package

Tags: laravel, authentication, file-upload, profile-picture, bootstrap-ui

i am trying to upload an image as a profile picture in laravel bootstrap auth package.
in this i am trying to change some package files to upload image. also i added a column in users table.

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'campus_id' => $data['campus_id'],
            'role' => $data['role'],
            'remarks' => $data['remarks'],
            'image' => $data['image'],
        ]);
    }
```

i make changes in Auth controller in validation function
also makes some changes in user store function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to move user profile image before create its entry inside database.

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $imageName = time().'.'.$data['image']->extension();
        //$data['image']->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
        $data['image']->storeAs('public/images', $imageName);        

        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'campus_id' => $data['campus_id'],
            'role' => $data['role'],
            'remarks' => $data['remarks'],
            'image' => $imageName,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Image [intervention](https://image.intervention.io/v2/introduction/installation) for this. After installing you can use it in your controller as `use Image;`

```
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $img_name = hexdec(uniqid()).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Image::make($image)->resize( 847.5, 431 )->save('uploads/sliders/'.$img_name);
    $image_path = 'uploads/sliders/'.$img_name;

    Slider::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'image' => $image_path,
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()
    ]);
```

1st you need to move your image to your desired directory inside public folder and save that directory in the database.